# “..so..that..” or “...too...that...”

Tags: grammar

I had an english exam (multiple choice) recently and there was a question which was something like this:

> A. He was **so** tired **that** he couldn’t do the homework
>
> B. He was **too** tired **that** he couldn’t do the homework
>
> C....
>
> D.....

I had to choose the answer which is grammatically correct, the answer that my school marked was **A**, however I think both **A** and **B** sound natural.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 5):

No, I don’t agree that both sound natural.

The natural pairings are:

- **so** [*adjective*] **that** [*independent clause*]; and
- **too** [*adjective*] **to** [*verb phrase*].

Examples:

- He was **so** tired **that** he fell asleep on the train.
- She was **too** tired **to** care.

The quote in your question matches the *so ...that* pattern, not the *too ... to* pattern.

Comment: Totally agree. "too...that..." really hurts my ears. Gave an "arrow up" ;)

Comment: Thanks virolino! Thanks for the formatting as well, @M.A.R., though I reverted to Rev 2 because I try to keep block quotes for direct quotes on ELL (& ELU).

Answer (score 3):

> A. *He was **so** tired **that he couldn’t do the homework**.*
>
> B. *He was **too** tired **that he couldn’t do the homework**.*

It's all about 'licensing', the specific requiring or permitting of complements.

The *that* clauses here are called 'indirect complements' because although they follow the adjective "tired" in head position, it is not the head that licences them, but the adverb that modifies "tired".

In A. the adverb "so" licenses the complement clause and is fine. But "too" doesn't licence declarative content clause like this, so B. is ungrammatical. 
Note, though, that "too" can license infinitivals: *He was too tired to do the homework.*

Answer (score 0):

Your school marked the right answer. As you have already been told, "so that" is used to introduce a clause of purpose. B would be correct if it were

> He was **too** tired **to** do his homework.

Comment: But there is no _so that_ and no clause of purpose in the example given.